# Implementing a concrete type's property override of its protocol extension default in array of metatypes

Tags: swift

I have created a process that loads resources and uses the type properties of certain metatypes of classes defined in my program. Since they are disparate types when instantiated yet similar in that they need their resources given all at the same time, I use an array of metatypes that conform to the `SomeProtocol` protocol to make an array of type `[SomeProtocol.Type]`. When iterating through the array and calling each type's `someDefaultInt` property (defaulted to `1` by an extension of `SomeProtocol`), the protocol extension's value is called even if a custom implementation is given by a concrete class conforming to the protocol (see below)

Note: The code below is written in Swift 5.2 so the `return` keyword may be omitted for the single-expression read-only type property `someDefaultInt` in each class

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    static var myInt: Int { get set }
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    static var someDefaultInt: Int { 1 }
}

class ConcreteType: SomeProtocol {
    static var myInt: Int = 4
    static var someDefaultInt: Int { 2 } // Custom implementation
}

class ConcreteTypeII: SomeProtocol {
    static var myInt: Int = 5
    static var someDefaultInt: Int { 3 } // Custom implementation
}

var someTypes: [SomeProtocol.Type] = [ConcreteType.self, ConcreteTypeII.self]
someTypes.forEach { print($0.myInt) }
someTypes.forEach { print($0.someDefaultInt) }
/*
    Prints
    4
    5
    1
    1
*/
```

Casting `$0` to a particular metatype does result in the correct custom implementation value of `someDefaultInt` being called. The question is: how can I ensure that the custom implementation  is called for each metatype if it is only known that they conform to the protocol? Is it necessary to know the metatypes used in the array beforehand or to implement a large `switch` statement with cases casting to particular metatypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `someDefaultInt` in the protocol definition if you want it to enjoy dynamic dispatch.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    static var myInt: Int { get set }
    static var someDefaultInt: Int { get }
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    static var someDefaultInt: Int { 1 }
}
```